# Pinescript stop loss on same bar as entry

Tags: pine-script

I have the below script and the stop loss is working as desired except it doesn't work on the entry bar. i.e. if the script enters at 1000, the stop loss won't take effect until the first bar has closed based on the chart's timeframe. Is there a way to set this as soon as the trade is placed? Or set a stop loss as soon as the trade is placed and the trailstop active at the same time? Trying to avoid that first entry bar from not having any stop loss protection. Any help is appreciated. thanks!

I tried using recalculate after order is filled but this causes repainting a lot of times and I don't want that.

```
//@version=5
strategy("TEST", overlay=true, default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity,
         default_qty_value = 100,
         initial_capital = 50000,
         max_labels_count = 300)

// --- Input parameters ---
var longTrailPerc = 2 * 0.01

// --- Time range filter ---
timeAllowed = input.session("0600-1900", "Allowed hours")
timeIsAllowed = time(timeframe.period, timeAllowed + ":1234567")
timeAllowed2 = input.session("0600-1500", "Allowed hours")
timeIsAllowed2 = time(timeframe.period, timeAllowed2 + ":1234567")


// === INPUT BACKTEST RANGE ===
i_from = input.time(defval = timestamp("20 Jun 2021 00:00 +0000"), title = "From")
i_thru = input.time(defval = timestamp("01 Mar 2025 00:00 +0000"), title = "Thru")

// === INPUT SHOW PLOT ===
i_show = input     (defval = true, title = "Show Date Range")

// === FUNCTION EXAMPLE ===
date() => time >= i_from and time <= i_thru  // create date function "within window of time"

// --- Entry and exit conditions ---
long_condition = close > ta.ema(close,9) and date()
exit_condition =  close < ta.ema(close,18) and date()

tradeOpenPL() =>
    sumProfit = 0.0
    for tradeNo = 0 to strategy.opentrades - 1
        sumProfit += strategy.opentrades.profit(tradeNo)
    result = sumProfit

// Determine trail stop loss prices
longStopPrice = 0.0

longStopPrice := if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    stopValue = close * (1 - longTrailPerc)
    math.max(stopValue, longStopPrice[1])
else
    0

// --- Strategy execution ---
if long_condition and strategy.position_size == 0 and timeIsAllowed
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)  
if  exit_condition and strategy.position_size > 0 and timeIsAllowed 
    strategy.close("Long", comment = "Exit1",qty = strategy.position_size)

percentAsPoints(pcnt) =>
    strategy.position_size != 0 ? (pcnt / 100 * strategy.position_avg_price / syminfo.mintick) : float(na)

if strategy.position_size > 0 and timeIsAllowed2
    strategy.exit("PT1", qty_percent = 30, profit = percentAsPoints(2), stop = longStopPrice, alert_profit = "PT1", alert_loss = "TRLSTP")
    strategy.exit("PT2", qty_percent = 30, profit = percentAsPoints(3), stop = longStopPrice, alert_profit = "PT2", alert_loss = "TRLSTP")
    strategy.exit("PT3", qty_percent = 30, profit = percentAsPoints(4), stop = longStopPrice, alert_profit = "PT3", alert_loss = "TRLSTP")
    strategy.exit("TRLSTP", profit = percentAsPoints(100), stop = longStopPrice, alert_loss = "TRLSTP")
```

Comment: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy.exit
`If an entry order was not filled, but an exit order is generated, the exit order will wait till entry order is filled and then the exit order is placed`. 

So you can place strategy.exit in the same condition with your strategy.entry call (but profit calculation should be changed because it uses `strategy.position_size` and `strategy.position_avg_price`, which is 0, because order is not filled yet.